# What is the purpose of the explicit keyword on a multi-argument constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit, explicit-constructor

I recently came across some weird looking class that had three constructors:

```
class Class
{
    public:
        explicit Class(int );

        Class(AnotherClass );

        explicit Class(YetAnotherClass, AnotherClass );

    // ...
}
```

This doesn't really make sense to me - I thought the explicit keyword is to protect compiler chosen construction from a foreign type.

Is this allowed? If it it, what does it mean?

Comment: this duplicate got more/better answers: [Why is explicit allowed for default constructors and constructors with 2 or more (non-default) parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467142/why-is-explicit-allowed-for-default-constructors-and-constructors-with-2-or-more)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In C++11 multi-parameter constructors can be implicitly converted to with brace initialization.

However, before C++11 `explicit` only applied to single-argument constructors. For multiple-argument constructors, it was ignored and [had no effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/wwywka61(v=vs.140)#the-explicit-keyword-and-problems-with-implicit-conversion).

Comment: With the caveat that if all but one of the multi-arg params have default values then it will have an effect

Comment: This has changed with C++11. Now multi-parameter constructors can be implicitly converted to with brace initialisation.

Comment: In addition to Shane's comment about C++11: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4467658

Answer (score 0):

First of all, constructors with multiple parameters can be used for implicit conversions too:

```cpp
struct S {
    S(int x, int y = 0);
};

S s = 123; // OK, x = 123, y = 0
```

While `explicit` was pointless prior to C++11 in some cases, there was no real benefit to banning it, only extra effort.
Even if C++ language designers would have wanted to ban `explicit` where it's pointless, the rule would be relatively complicated, and not as simple as "allowed for ≤ 1 parameter". See [Why is explicit allowed for default constructors and constructors with 2 or more (non-default) parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4467142/5740428) for more on the topic of language design.

Secondly, since C++11, `explicit` forbids list-initialization without specifying the type:

```cpp
struct T {
    explicit T(int x, int y);
};

T a{1, 2};    // OK
T b = {1, 2}; // error

T foo() {
    return T{1, 2}; // OK
    return {1, 2};  // error
}
```