# Why is explicit allowed for default constructors and constructors with 2 or more (non-default) parameters?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-design, explicit, explicit-constructor

I understand that constructors with one (non-default) parameter act like implicit convertors, which convert from that parameter type to the class type. However, `explicit` can be used to qualify any constructor, those with no parameters (default constructor) or those with 2 or more (non-default) parameters.

Why is explicit allowed on these constructors? Is there any example where this is useful to prevent implicit conversion of some sort?

Comment: Falmarri: If it is not prevented, is there some example where it is useful on a default constructor or >=2 parameter constructor?

Comment: See Adrian's answer. Why should you prevent it?

Comment: Falmarri: I am sorry if my query implied I "do not want" to use it on such constructors. Rather, I was curious to know "why" it is allowed.

Answer (score 39):

One reason certainly is because it doesn't hurt.

One reason where it's needed is, if you have default arguments for the first parameter. The constructor becomes a default constructor, but can still be used as converting constructor

```
struct A {
  explicit A(int = 0); // added it to a default constructor
};
```

C++0x makes actual use of it for multi parameter constructors. In C++0x, an *initializer list* can be used to initialize a class object. The philosophy is

- if you use `= { ... }`, then you initialize the object with a sort of "compound value" that conceptually represents the abstract value of the object, and that you want to have converted to the type.
- if you use a `{ ... }` initializer, you directly call the constructors of the object, not necessarily wanting to specify a conversion.

Consider this example

```
struct String {
    // this is a non-converting constructor
    explicit String(int initialLength, int capacity);
};

struct Address {
    // converting constructor
    Address(string name, string street, string city);
};

String s = { 10, 15 }; // error!
String s1{10, 15}; // fine

Address a = { "litb", "nerdsway", "frankfurt" }; // fine
```

In this way, C++0x shows that the decision of C++03, to allow explicit on other constructors, wasn't a bad idea at all.

Comment: So, `explicit` on a multiparameter constructor gives a result similar to `explicit` on a copy constructor.

Comment: @James similar to explicit on any one-argument-callable constructor :) But the difference of list initialization is that it still considers an explicit constructor. When it is selected, a diagnostic is risen. Unlike `T t = v` which just ignores explicit constructors, possibly preferring a non-explicit constructor, which was deemed by the committee to be a bad thing.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably just a convenience; there's no reason to *dis*-allow it, so why make life difficult for code generators, etc? If you checked, then code generation routines would have to have an extra step verifying how many parameters the constructor being generated has.

According to [various](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2004/08/31/Explicit-Constructors.aspx) [sources](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=512723), it has no effect at all when applied to constructors that cannot be called with exactly one argument.

Comment: re "without exactly one parameter", you mean, no effect when applied to constructor that cannot be called with exactly one argument. there's a difference. ;-)

Comment: Subtle distinction, but okay :) Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it was to support maintainance. By using `explicit` on multi-argument constructors one might avoid inadvertently introducing implicit conversions when adding defaults to arguments. Although I don't believe that; instead, I think it's just that lots of things are allowed in C++ simply to not make the language definition more complex than it already it is.

Perhaps the most infamous case is returning a reference to non-`static` local variable. It would need additional complex rules to rule out all the "meaningless" things without affecting anything else. So it's just allowed, yielding UB if you *use* that reference.

Or for constructors, you're allowed to define any number of default constructors as long as their signatures differ, but with more than one it's rather difficult to have any of them invoked by default. :-)

A better question is perhaps, why is `explicit` not also allowed on conversion operators?

Well it will be, in C++0x. So there was no good reason why not. The actual reason for not allowing `explicit` on conversion operators might be as prosaic as oversight, or the struggle to get `explicit` adopted in the first place, or simple prioritization of the committee's time, or whatever.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 7):

According to the **High Integrity C++ Coding Standard** *you should declare all sinlge parameter constructor as* **explicit** *for avoiding an incidentally usage in type conversions*. In the case it is a multiple argument constructor suppose you have a constructor that accepts multiple parametres each one has a default value, converting the constructor in some kind of default constructor and also a conversion constructor:

```
class C { 
    public: 
    C( const C& );   // ok copy 
    constructor C(); // ok default constructor 
    C( int, int ); // ok more than one non-default argument 

    explicit C( int ); // prefer 
    C( double ); // avoid 
    C( float f, int i=0 ); // avoid, implicit conversion constructor 
    C( int i=0, float f=0.0 ); // avoid, default constructor, but 
                               // also a conversion constructor 
}; 
void bar( C const & ); 
void foo() 
{ 
    bar( 10 );  // compile error must be 'bar( C( 10 ) )' 
    bar( 0.0 ); // implicit conversion to C 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason to explicit a default constructor is to avoid an error-prone implicit conversion on the right hand side of an assignment when there is an overload to `class_t::operator=` that accepts an object with type `U` and `std::is_same_v<U, class_t> == false`. An assignment like `class_t_instance = {}` can lead us to an undesirable result if we have, for example, an `observable<T>` that overloads the move assignment operator to something like `observable<T>::operator=(U&&)`, while `U` should be convertible to `T`. The confusing assignment could be written with an assignment of a default constructed `T` (observed type object) in mind, but in reality the programmer is "erasing" the `observable<T>` because this assignment is the same as `class_t_instance = class_t_instance{}` if the default constructor is implicit. Take a look at a toy implementation of an `observable<T>`:

```
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
 
template<typename T>
struct observable {
    using observed_t = T;
    
    //With an implicit default constructor we can assign `{}` instead
    //of the explicit version `observable<int>{}`, but I consider this
    //an error-prone assignment because the programmer can believe
    //that he/she is defining a default constructed
    //`observable<T>::observed_t` but in reality the left hand side
    //observable will be "erased", which means that all observers will
    //be removed.
    explicit observable() = default;
    
    explicit observable(observed_t o) : _observed(std::move(o)) {}
 
    observable(observable&& rhs) = default;
    observable& operator=(observable&& rhs) = default;
 
    template<typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<U>, observable>,
        observable&>
    operator=(U&& rhs) {
        _observed = std::forward<U>(rhs);
        _after_change(_observed);
        return *this;
    }
 
    template<typename F>
    auto after_change(F&& f)
    { return _after_change.connect(std::forward<F>(f)); }
    
    const observed_t& observed() const noexcept
    { return _observed; }
private:
    observed_t _observed;
    boost::signals2::signal<void(T)> _after_change;
};

int main(){
    observable<int> o;
    o.after_change([](auto v){ std::cout << "changed to " << v << std::endl; }); //[1]
    o = 5;
 
    //We're not allowed to do the assignment `o = {}`. The programmer
    //should be explicit if he/she desires to "clean" the observable.
    o = observable<int>{};
    
    o = 10; //the above reaction [1] is not called;
    
    //outputs:
    //changed to 5
}
```