# C++11: in-class initializaton with "= {}" doesn't work with explicit constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, explicit-constructor, in-class-initialization

In C++11 we can do in-class initialization using a "brace-or-equal-initializer" (words from the standard) like this:

```
struct Foo
{
  /*explicit*/ Foo(int) {}
};

struct Bar
{
  Foo foo = { 42 };
};
```

But if we un-comment `explicit`, it no longer compiles.  GCC 4.7 and 4.9 say this:

```
error: converting to ‘Foo’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor ‘Foo::Foo(int)’
```

I found this surprising.  Is it really the intention of the C++11 standard that this code doesn't compile?

Removing the `=` fixes it: `Foo foo { 42 };` but I personally find this harder to explain to people who have been used to the form with `=` for decades, and since the standard refers to a "brace-or-equal-initializer" it's not obvious why the good old way doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: The `{}` initializer syntax is kind of a hack and it has a bunch of weird corner cases like this

Comment: I thought you had to use double braces - try it with `Foo foo = { { 42 } };`

Comment: @CarlBurnett: double braces seem to do the same thing as single braces--still broken.

Comment: Does "brace-or-equal-initializer" mean that you have to use either "brace" or "equal" but not both?

Comment: @Matt McNabb: it's not so much `{}` being a hack as using `=` and hoping for elided construction that's a hack, but I do personally prefer it notationally.  Anyway, given ***elision is an optimisation not a guarantee***, ignoring `explicit` means you risk an extra unintended construction.  Seems that requiring code to either explicitly reflect that risk - `Foo foo = Foo{ 42 };` - is reasonable when the constructor's marked with `explicit`.   The verbosity pushes people to consider and simplify.  Tedious though.

Comment: Related: [What could go wrong if copy-list-initialization allowed explicit constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157041/what-could-go-wrong-if-copy-list-initialization-allowed-explicit-constructors)

Comment: @TonyD Agreed, but you may be wrong about the elision. [According to Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) the elision is in fact guaranteed. That said, I don’t know what he’s basing this assertion on.

Comment: Related reading on [explicit with multi-parameter constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467142/why-is-explicit-allowed-for-default-constructors-and-constructors-with-2-or-more/4467658#4467658).

Comment: @TonyD `= {}` has always been aggregate initialization, which follows its own rules. No temporaries involved. Nowadays, `= {}` is list-initialization, which follows its own rules, and still does not involve temporaries (here).

Comment: Konrad / dyp: solid point... `= { }` specifically is quite distinct from other `= ...` initialisation, and I hadn't realised elision was guaranteed for this specific case - nice!

Comment: @JohnZwinck One could guess that this has to do with consistency. The initialization via `=` and initializing function parameters is the same *copy-initialization*, and `void bar(Foo); bar({});` *implicitly* creates a `Foo`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just read over the appropriate sections of the standard: I believe Herb is wrong. `Foo a=x;` where `x` is not a `Foo` is equivalent to `Foo a=Foo(x);` where `Foo(x)` is restricted to non-`explicit` constructors(footnote 1). While elision is practically guaranteed, it is not actually guaranteed.  The copy/move ctor need exist, and implementations are allowed to not elide. Footnote 1: Or, to be precise, `template<class T, class Arg> T implicit( Arg&& arg) { return {std::forward<Arg>(arg)}; }` then `Foo a=x;` is almost equivalent to `Foo a=implicit<Foo>(x);`, except for lists.Gah

Comment: @Yakk According to dyp's comment above that's wrong, and `={}` follows the special rules of aggregate initialisation. Unfortunately I cannot check the standard myself at the moment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm.  Yep, 8.5 actually led me down a bad path: while it implies (to my reading) that `Foo x={a};` is copy-initialization, it is actually copy-list-initialization covered in 8.5.4.  And copy-list-initialization is identical to direct-list-initialization except if an `explicit` constructor is chosen, it is blocked.  Unlike `Foo x=a;` no temporary is created, logically or not.  So [this works](http://ideone.com/3Ewhjx) -- blocked copy/move, `Foo a={x};` style, compiles.  Without `{}` does not compile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can't explain the rationale behind this, but I can repeat the obvious.

> I found this surprising. Is it really the intention of the C++11
>   standard that this code doesn't compile?

§13.3.1.7

> In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the
>   initialization is ill-formed.

---

> Removing the = fixes it: `Foo foo { 42 };` but I personally find this
>   harder to explain to people who have been used to the form with = for
>   decades, and since the standard refers to a
>   "brace-or-equal-initializer" it's not obvious why the good old way
>   doesn't work in this scenario.

`Foo foo { 42 }` is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), whereas the equal sign (with braces) makes it [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Another answer reasons that because compilation fails for [copy-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (equal sign without braces), then it shouldn't be surprising that it also fails for copy-list-initialization, but the two fail for different reasons.

cppreference:

> Direct-initialization is more permissive than copy-initialization:
>   copy-initialization only considers non-explicit constructors and
>   user-defined conversion functions, while direct-initialization
>   considers all constructors and implicit conversion sequences.

And their page on the [explicit specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

> Specifies constructors and <sup>(since C++11)</sup> conversion
>   operators that don't allow implicit conversions or
>   copy-initialization.

On the other hand, for copy-list-initialization:

> *T object* = {*arg1*, *arg2*, *...*};     (10)
>
> 10) on the right-hand-side of the equals sign (similar to copy-initialization)
>
> - Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
>       consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
>       that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. **If this stage
>       produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
>       copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
>       copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all)**

As discussed in [What could go wrong if copy-list-initialization allowed explicit constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157041/what-could-go-wrong-if-copy-list-initialization-allowed-explicit-constructors), the compilation fails because the explicit constructor is selected but is not allowed to be used.

Answer (score 12):

If `Foo(int)` is `explicit`, then this won't compile also:

```
Foo foo = 42;
```

So for "people who have been used to the form with `=` for decades" it won't be a surprise that the form with `{}` doesn't compile either.

Comment: `Foo foo = 42` *implicitly* creates a `Foo` prvalue to initialize `foo` with. This is not the case for `Foo foo = {42}`, which does *not* implicitly create a `Foo`.

Comment: I'm with @dyp: I understand why `Foo foo = 42` won't work, and I'm OK with it.  I am still bewildered as to why `Foo foo = { 42 }` doesn't work...it seems from another answer here that this may be what the standard intended or at least anticipated, but it seems...bad.

Answer (score 7):

> **widget w = {x};**
>
> This is called “copy list initialization.” It means the same as widget w{x}; except that explicit constructors cannot be used. It’s guaranteed that only a single constructor is called.

From http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

See the rest of the article for a more detailed discussion on the various ways you can initialise an object.