# explicit non-single parameter constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit, explicit-constructor

Can anyone explain why does non-single parameter constructor marked as explicit compile?
As far as I understand this is absolutely useless keyword here, so why does this compile without error?

```
class X
{
public:
    explicit X(int a, int b) { /* ... */}
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicit keyword on multi-arg constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118680/explicit-keyword-on-multi-arg-constructor)

Comment: It works for completeness. Although it indeed does nothing, there's no reason for it cause the compilation to fail.

Comment: it happens with me regularly. First I have explicit single parameter constructor then I add the second parameter and forget to remove `explicit`

Comment: As a rule, the C++ standard tries to specify as uniform rules as possible to make the syntax act as unsurprising as possible when combining feature. So, I think the counter-question should be: what reason is there to explicitly disallow marking such a constructor as `explicit`?

Comment: There can be lots of statements that may do nothing, I don't see why keep them to work. Writing unnecessary things makes the code dirty and one reading the code may spend time to understand why this constructor is marked as explicit while the actual reason is simple: programmer just forgot to remove explicit after adding parameter to constructor.

Comment: The question linked by @FrédéricHamidi is NOT a dupe, as it is obsolete.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467142/why-is-explicit-allowed-for-default-constructors-and-constructors-with-2-or-more/4467658#4467658) is a proper dupe.

Comment: I can definitely see a benefit of allowing `explicit` on constructors with multiple arguments. For example, it makes it easy to create variadic templates  to generate constructors without accidentally introducing implicit casts via those constructors.

Comment: @jrok, please vote to close this question as such, then. I already burned my close vote, but there can be several duplicates to one question.

Comment: Guys, you are talking about C++11, I'm talking about C++98 or C++03 when there was no `{}` initialization, no variadic templates and so on...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I did that. OP: If you're interested in C++03 answers, you should explicitly say so. It's 2013, mind you.

Comment: Explicit operator - yes, explicit constructor - no

Comment: Yes, it's 2013 :) but still there is no compiler completely supporting C++11, right?

Comment: Actually, both gcc and clang fully support C++11.

Comment: My gcc doesn't support C++11 fully, probably the version is old. Anyway, there is special tag for C++11 here, I used C++ tag.

Comment: These days the C++ is taken as implying "the current standard today", and the C++11 seems to be used for *C++11 only* issues. So it is well worth specifying C++03 when you ask a question, otherwise most people will assume C++11, even if you don't have that tag.

Comment: I do think it is a reasonable assumption that a question in C++ is taken to mean the C++11 standard, seeing as it has been the international standard for defining what C++ is for 2 years already and that there are multiple fully conforming compilers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++03, and in this particular case, it makes no sense for a two parameter constructor to be marked `explicit`. But it could make sense here:

```
explicit X(int i, int j=42);
```

So, marking a two parameter constructor with `explicit` does not have to be an error.

In C++11, this use of explicit would prevent you from doing this:

```
X x = {1,2};
```

Comment: Yes, but in my example compiler can understand that there is no sense and constructor cannot be called with one argument, so it could give a compile time error.

Comment: @axe Yes, I agree, perhaps the rules of the language could have been stricter about this. The question is whether it is worth adding more complications to the rules for the potential benefit. Now, fast forward to 2011 and C++11, and `explicit` *does* serve a purpose in multi-parameter constructors. So one could argue that it was lucky that the rule was not made stricter originally.

Comment: OK. I think we can close the question. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 9):

Not entirely true.

**In C++11, constructors with multiple arguments can be implicitly converted using brace initialisation.**